# How to change the value and the function of a button on flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, button, listener

I have a function named `saveData` which is executed on pressing a button. I want if I click on the button I execute saveData function and the value of the button become stop then when I click on stop the function should be fininish.
this is the button code:

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      saveData();
    },
    child: Text('Save Data'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: Please be kind to accept one of the provided answers below if any of them did help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you want is simply to create a flag to control which button (text/action) is shown at any given moment:

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: isSaving ? Finish : saveData,
  child: isSaving ? const Text("Stop") : const Text("Save Data"),
)
```

---

Try the following working complete sample to see what i mean:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isSaving = false;

  Future saveData() async {

    isSaving = true;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("Saving data..."),duration: Duration(hours: 1),)
    );

    setState(() {    });

  }

  void Finish() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("Saving data stopped..."),duration: Duration(seconds: 1),)
    );

    isSaving = false;

    setState(() {    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: isSaving ? Finish : saveData,
          child: isSaving ? const Text("Stop") : const Text("Save Data"),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will produce a result like:

State 1

[image]

After *Save Data* is tapped

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need state management.

**State Management**

This is a way to manage your user interface controls such as text fields, buttons, images, etc. It controls what and when something should display or perform an action. More about Flutter state management [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

**Codebase Sample**

```dart
    String name = ""; // setting an empty name variable

    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                    name = "new name"; // updating the name variable with setState
                });
            },
        child: Text('Save Data'),
      ),
    ),
```

Now, to implement your idea. You need a bool variable that changes the state on the button click action. To do that, look what I did below

```dart
    bool isClicked = false;

    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
                setState(() => isClicked = !isClicked); // change click state
                if (isClicked) {
                    // do something on click
                } else {
                    // do something off click
                }
            },
        child: Text(isClicked ? "Stop" : "Save Data"), // if isClicked display "Stop" else display "Save Data"
      ),
    ),
```

Another way to do this is to create two different functions. One for saving user data, and the other of stop and calling the action based on a bool state.

```dart
    onPressed: isSaving ? saveData : stop,
```

You can use the method above to update your user data as well if any misunderstand or need future help, comment below. Bye

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a **state management** problem.

you get more information about state management from [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Here a code for solve your problem

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeView(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  bool _savePressed = false;

  void _save() {
    // TODO do whatever you want
  }

  void _stop() {
    // TODO do whatever you want
  }

  void _onButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _savePressed = !_savePressed;
      _savePressed ? _save() : _stop();
    });
  }

  String get _getButtonText => _savePressed ? "Stop" : "Save";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: _onButtonPressed,
          child: Text(_getButtonText),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```